# Is it possible to delete all content of a folder?

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2008

I managed to write this, but it doesn't work

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%

    'Delete All Subfolders and Files in a Folder And deletes itself

    Function discardScript()
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        strScript = Wscript.ScriptFullName
        objFSO.DeleteFile(strScript)
    End Function

    Dim folderName
    Dim x
    Dim currentPath
    Const DeleteReadOnly = TRUE
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    folderName = Request.QueryString("folderName")

    A = Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")
    response.write("PATH_INFO A: "&A&"<br />")
    B = split(A,"/")
    For x = LBound(B) to UBound(B)
        response.write("PATH_INFO B["&x&"]: "&B(x)&"<br />")
    Next
    C = B(ubound(B)-1)&"/"
    response.write("PATH_INFO C: "&C&"<br />")
    if (folderName <> "") then
        currentPath = C&folderName&"/*"
        response.write("Deleting '"&folderName&"'...<br />")
        if objFSO.FileExists(currentPath) then
            objFSO.DeleteFile(currentPath), DeleteReadOnly
        end if

        objFSO.DeleteFolder(currentPath),DeleteReadOnly
    else
        response.write("No folder specified")
    end if

    'objFSO.DeleteFile("C:\FSO\*"), DeleteReadOnly
    'objFSO.DeleteFolder("C:\FSO\*"),DeleteReadOnly

%>
</body>
</html>
```

> Errore di run-time di Microsoft VBScript error '800a004c'
>   Impossibile trovare il percorso
>   /index.asp, riga 37

Which means:

> Run-time Error...Path not found...index.asp row 37

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @schudel and some research I got this, hope it's useful

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%

    'Delete All Subfolders and Files in a Folder And deletes itself

    Function discardScript()
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        strScript = Wscript.ScriptFullName
        objFSO.DeleteFile(strScript)
    End Function

    Dim folderName
    Dim deleteScript
    Dim x
    Dim fullPath
    Const DeleteReadOnly = TRUE
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    folderName = Request.QueryString("folderName")

    BASE = Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH")

    response.write("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH = "&BASE&"<br />")

    if (folderName <> "") then
        'DELETE VARIABLES
        fullPath = BASE&folderName&"\"
        Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        if (objFS.FolderExists(fullPath)) then
            Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(fullPath) 
            Set objFiles = objFolder.Files
            dim curFile
        else
            response.write("Folder '"&folderName&"' does not exists!")
            response.End
        end if
        'DELETE PROCESS
        response.write("Deleting content from '"&fullPath&"' ...<br />")
        For each curFile in objFiles
            response.write("Deleting <strong>FILE</strong>: '"&curFile&"' ...")
            objFS.DeleteFile(curFile), DeleteReadOnly
        Next
        response.write("Deleting <strong>FOLDER</strong>: '"&objFolder&"' ...")
        objFS.DeleteFolder(objFolder), DeleteReadOnly
    else
        response.write("No folder specified")
    end if

    if (deleteScript = "YES") then
        discardScript()
    end if

%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why did you say "classic ASP" and tag this as `asp-classic` if you're using Web Forms, which runs on ASP.NET, which is completely different from Classic ASP?

Comment: Because I need to do this on Classic ASP

Comment: If you need to do it on Classic ASP, why did you tag it as ASP.NET and show .NET code?

Comment: Because I don't know the difference among all these...

Comment: Well you need to figure out what exactly it is you're using. Do the files end with .aspx or with asp?

Comment: .asp, I was told it's Classic ASP or VBScript

Comment: Then it's classic ASP, and not ASP.NET.

Comment: In a nutshell, ASP.NET is the "next generation" of classic ASP. It's still running under IIS, but is complied into DLL files and is a whole new world of coding.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I'm counting not to work with ASP for a long time. I love PHP and Javascript and I want to keep on that side of the moon :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetFolder will return a folder object containing a files and a subfolders collection. 
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262405(v=vs.60).aspx for more information.

```vbs
  Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder("c:\myFolder\") 
  Set objFiles = objFolder.Files
  dim curFile

  For each curFile in objFiles
    objFS.DeleteFile(curFile)
  Next
```

Comment: Tip for future posts: adding `<!-- language: lang-vbs -->` before the code block will make it prettified as VBS code. :)